# iptables chain name no more than 30 chars?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, iptables

I can use 31 chars chain name in Debian 6 (iptables 1.4.8), but in Ubuntu 11 (iptables 1.4.10), I can't... Is it possible to let Ubuntu support 30+ chars chain name?

Comment: Do you really need names that long?

Comment: On CentOS this limit is defined in the netfilter source (header) files. Specifically, `#define XT_FUNCTION_MAXNAMELEN 30` in `/usr/include/linux/netfilter/x_tables.h`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You'll have to download the source from [netfilter.org](http://www.netfilter.org/index.html) or get [your distro](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/)'s soure code. once you've done that make a suitable change and recompile.

Now you have an unsupported, private version of netfilter/iptables which brings all kinds of it's own problems with patches, updates and dependencies.

It really would be much better and supported if you just used shorter names.